# days of the month

Tags: sql-server

I know this sounds ridiculous... I know... but I want to be able to select the first 7 days of the month and get a result like this.

this is what I have:

```
SELECT row_number () OVER (ORDER BY DateD), *
  FROM (SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE ()) AS 'DateName', getdate () AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 1) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 1 AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 2) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 2 AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 3) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 3 AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 4) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 4 AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 5) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 5 AS 'DateD'
        UNION
        SELECT DATENAME (dw, GETDATE () + 6) AS 'DateName',
               getdate () + 6 AS 'DateD') queryTable
```

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend against `AS 'alias'` syntax. Some forms have been deprecated and it is confusing anyway because many people look at that and think it is a string. Use `[square brackets]` for identifiers that need to be escaped, not string delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach to getting `@n` days in the current month. If you need it for a different month, just replace `GETDATE()` with a variable that represents any datetime value within the month you want.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (@n) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
  FROM sys.all_objects
),
y(d,n) AS
(
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n-1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)),
   n FROM x
)
SELECT 
  RowNumber = n, 
  [Weekday] = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, d), 
  [Date_In_Ambiguous_Format] = CONVERT(CHAR(10), d, 101),
  [Date_In_Proper_DataType] = d
FROM y;
```

Please see this blog series about generating sets without loops and without repeating code:

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1
http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2
http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Comment: @bluefeet beauty is in the eye of the beholder. :-) Mine is a lot less code but probably needs quite a bit of explanation if the reader doesn't check the blog posts...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really ugly query that gives you the result:

```
SELECT row_number () OVER (ORDER BY DateD), *
FROM 
(
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateName', 
        DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 3, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 3, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 4, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 4, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 5, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 5, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
    UNION
    SELECT DATENAME (dw, DateAdd(day, 6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))) AS 'DateName',
           DateAdd(day, 6, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) AS 'DateD'
) queryTable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8121)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive CTE:

```
WITH dayscte ( d ) 
     AS (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AS d 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(d, 1, d) 
         FROM   dayscte 
         WHERE  Datepart(day, d) < 7)  -- number of days you want
SELECT d, 
       Datepart(wk, d) AS week_number, 
       Datename(dw, d) AS day_name, 
       Datename(m, d)  AS month_name, 
       Datename(q, d)  AS [quarter] 
FROM   dayscte 
OPTION (maxrecursion 800);
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8136/0)

Comment: Just FYI recursive CTEs are fine for small sets but they become exponentially more expensive as the set gets larger (see my blog series for evidence).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks, i've mentioned it because OP wanted just the first seven days of a given month.

Comment: Sure, I'm just adding the comment because a future reader might want the whole month, 6 months, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, - (DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) - 1), CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101)) as DateDay
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DateDay + 1
    FROM Dates
    WHERE DATEPART(DAY, DateDay) < 7
)

SELECT
    DATEPART(DAY, DateDay),
    DATENAME(DW, DateDay),
    DateDay
FROM Dates
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server, you can query master..spt_values to get a list of numbers (not an entire list of numbers, but definitely 1 to 7):

```
SELECT 
   row_number () OVER (ORDER BY Number) as Row, 
   DATENAME (dw,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-Number),GetDate()),101) ) AS DtName,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GetDate())-Number),GetDate()),101), 101) As Dt
FROM (SELECT Number FROM master..spt_values WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 7 AND Type = 'P') t
```

Just another approach -- have fun with it!  And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8152).

Good luck.